# How to disable APT web service validation in Eclipse 4.4 edition for JavaEE Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, validation

I have installed the JavaEE edition of Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) and it contains a validator that generates the invalid errors (4144 items that haven't been a problem in 5 years of production use) for web services:

- `@WebMethod` is only supported on classes annotated with `@WebService`
- `@WebService` annotation contains an endpointInterface attribute. No methods annotated with `@WebMethod` allowed in implementation class
- etc.

These errors are prevalent in generated classes so there's little we can do about them (for now).

In order to make my Eclipse installation useful, I'd like to disable the plugin that generates these messages. As we use [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) to generate the web service classes, I have removed the CXF plugins from my Eclipse installation to no avail. I have looked in the settings to see if I can disable the generated warnings for web services but failed to discover these specific errors.

Even disabling all validations in the Preferences→Validation pane still keeps the APT web services validation enabled. Even suspending all validations doesn't do the trick.

The errors don't contain any information as to which plugin is responsible for them. So the question is two fold:

1. <s>which plugin is responsible for these errors?</s>
2. how do I disable these specific validations?

Comment: In Eclipse, problem markers are persisted, so removing a plugin that adds them does not remove them. If you suspect that you removed the offending plugin, you will need to create a new workspace and import your existing projects. That's the only way I know to re-calculate all problems from a clean slate.

Comment: A clean build will remove those errors. Another option is to delete the errors manually. However a new build will introduce them again–unless you disable/remove the offending plugin.

Comment: A clean build is a build type sent to participating builders. Eclipse platform doesn't do anything beyond that. It certainly doesn't clear all markers. It is responsibility of individual builders to do that based on their own heuristics. Of course, if the builder is missing, because the plugin has been uninstalled, the markers become orphaned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin responsible for generating these errors is: `org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.core_1.0.400.v201404292132.jar` according to the code search I did (specifically the [`WebMethodCheckForWebServiceRule class`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/webtools/org.eclipse.webtools.incubator.git/plain/webservices/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.core/src/org/eclipse/jst/ws/internal/jaxws/core/annotations/validation/WebMethodCheckForWebServiceRule.java) is responsible for one of the generated errors)

Comment: Disabling the plugin from the JavaEE version seems impossible. In anycase,  we opted instead to provision our own custom Eclipse configuration using yoxos.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I can get rid of these validation errors by going to project properties>Java compiler>Annotation processing and then disabling annotation processing for the project. Tested on Eclipse Luna.

I hope this helps!